# Copy values of multiple cells on form submit into a single cell in a different Google Sheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to grab multiple cells from the last row of a Google Sheet upon a form submittal  and copy them to a single cell in different sheet.

How do I combine the values in this array into one value?  I'd like to put a comma and space between the data.

```
 var daterange = sourcesheet.getRange("H"+source_last_row+":Q"+source_last_row);
```

I'm not even sure the query is correct.  The Logger says "Range".  :\

I am grabbing the values below this in the script.

```
 var source_range6_values = daterange.getValues();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logger returns "Range" because your variable is just a range. To get an array of the values in that range, you need to use the [.getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getValues%28%29) method.

```
var daterange = sourcesheet.getRange("H"+source_last_row+":Q"+source_last_row);
var daterangeVals = daterange.getValues();
```

You can then use the [.toString()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tostring_array.asp) method to convert the array to string.

That will return the values separated by a comma. As you want a comma and a space, you could then use the [.replace()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp) method on the string.

Comment: I used toString() like you'd suggested and the logger looks correct.  [14-04-27 19:18:53:448 CDT] [Mon Feb 02 14:01:00 GMT-06:00 2015, Tue Feb 02 01:00:00 GMT-06:00 2016, , , , , , , , ] but when I try to set the values in the target sheet target6.setValues(source_range6_values); I get an error on that line that says, Incorrect range width, was 10 but should be 1 (line 84, file "Code")